# Editar/Reasignar Primary Key al copiar tabla - Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Se puede editar un campo al mismo tiempo que lo copio?
Tengo una query que me copia una tabla, y tengo que editar la PK de origen que puede ser cualquier número, a la PK destino que le corresponga (si la anterior fila destino (test) es 5, pues la que copio sera 6, la Id de DB puede ser cualquier número).

En el código de abajo la PK es id, la tabla origen es DB y Destino es test.

```
use DB
GO

INSERT INTO test.dbo.tabla (Id,Campo2)
--Aqui tengo que reasignar Id al que le corresponga
select Id,Campo2
-- tabla de DB
       FROM tabla 
       where Id = 16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Lo primero de todo, discúlpame si esta solución la habías planteado pero no la necesitas para solucionar tu problema).*

Con un INSERT FROM SELECT consigues el objetivo que te marcas, pero por lo que he entendido en tu pregunta, el valor ID quieres que sea secuencial. ¿Por qué no diseñar entonces tu Primary Key como valor autonumérico secuencial?

De ese modo, no tendrías que preocuparte por averiguar el valor de Id a la hora de añadir uno nuevo. En el atributo IDENTITY marcas inicio e incremento del valor id. Por ejemplo: IDEMNTITY (1,1) quiere decir que comenzarías con Id=1 e irías incrementando de 1 en 1 el valor del Id por cada INSERT.

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo sería el diseño:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(
Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
Campo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Id));
```

Y un ejemplo del INSERT basado en tu ejemplo, donde no tendrías que preocuparte por el valor anterior de Id para meter el siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
Select Campo2
From Tabla
Where Id=16
```

Answer (score 0):

En el insert into tiene que estar las columnas que se va a insertar, y basta con editar el valor que se inserta al que se desea:

> use DB GO
>
> INSERT INTO test.dbo.tabla (Id,Campo2)
>
> select ***6***, Campo2
>
> FROM tabla
>
> where Id = 16

Pregunta similar en ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879830/select-modify-and-insert-into-the-same-table